# Woogles puzzle: Why is K9 WILL significantly better than 2M WOE?

Tags: scrabble

I'm confused.  I did the Woogles.io [puzzle](https://woogles.io/puzzle/Mip9UApDHUqYj2x9sKqYEo):

> [image: Woogles.io screenshot]

I played 2M WOE which scores 34 points, but the answer is K9 WILL which scores 28 points.  The Woogles.io analysis bot indeed prefers WILL, despite it scoring less:

[image: Woogles.io analysis screenshot]

That seems like a big difference.  I'm fairly new to Scrabble, so I'm not sure what the big idea here is.  I'm guessing it's because the leave of NRO (after playing WILL) is better than the leave of LLRNI (after playing (WOE).

**Question**: Why is K9 WILL significantly better than 2M WOE?

Comment: Does the puzzle give the current score?

Comment: @Allure Current score usually not all that relevant in mid-game, only near the very end.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact how so? If you're up 70 points in that board state, WOE makes plenty of sense to keep the board closed. If you're down 70 points, WILL might be a necessary risk to take (to open bingo lines).

Comment: @Allure I wouldn't be worried about that type of strategy in mid-game, only towards the end. But everyone has their own way of playing.

Answer (score 9):

The problem is definitely the leave. Ls are a pain, two of them doubly so. They are relatively hard to use. The rest of the letters - NRO or NRI - are essentially the same, so ending up with 4 new letters instead of two letters and not having the Ls any more gives you much better odds for the next move.

It is also not purely about point values. Yes, giving up more one point tiles gives you a higher average point value for your replacement tiles. But there are points and there are points. I'd gladly keep two Ts over two Ls. On higher point letters, I much prefer an M or a P to a C (all 3 points) and an F, H, W or Y to a V (all 4 points).

Look at it another way - NRO gives you a decent chance at a Bingo. LLNRI does not.

Comment: 100% agree with this. It's all about the leave. Only small comment: sometimes a V can be a better bingo tile than, say F or W, because of suffixes like -IVE . . . though in general you are right V is awful :^P

Comment: It isn't that V can't be a useful letter. But in general F and W are better because of things like this situation, where W gets used in both directions - doesn't happen so much with a V.

Comment: Yes, not appearing in any two letter words is the main reason why V is bad, same with C. Though they are decent bingo tiles.

Comment: @qdread Yeah, it is possible to UNCOVER some decent moves.

Comment: *NRO gives you a decent chance at a Bingo. LLNRI does not* - Where are you going to play the bingo if you get one, though?

Comment: @Allure Impossible to say for sure without the new letters. But there is an R which makes a good start for a lot of words at D14

Answer (score 3):

The big difference is how valuable the tiles you are left with is, how valuable the replacement tiles should be, and how likely you are to be able to use them better on your next turn.

The average point value for a scrabble tile is 2.87. Your tiles are worth 10 points (1.43 Average). WILL gets rid of 4 tiles worth 7 points (1.75 average) leaving you with 3 tiles average value 1, for an expected average on your next turn of 2.07 for your tiles. WO(E) gets rid of 2 tiles worth 5 points (2.5 average) leaving you with 5 tiles average value 1, for an expected average on your next turn of 1.53 for your tiles. Both also leave you with one vowel, but drawing 4 tiles off WILL makes you much more likely to be able to draw a second vowel, making it more likely to have better play options for your next turn.

It's not always about what scores the most points now, it's about what gives you the best chance over the whole game, playing longer words, drawing more tiles, and having a better set of tiles for the next turn is important too.

Answer (score 0):

There's one key piece of information missing here - what the score currently is. This is important because a bingo is worth about 70 points. If you're up 70 points, then you want to close off potential bingo lanes. If you're down 70 points, then you need to open them up. If the score is between +/- 70, then you play normally and give luck a chance.

Right now, the board is pretty closed. It is still possible to bingo, but it's not easy to place a 7-letter word even if you have the right tiles. The most important bingo lanes are:

- A 7-letter bingo adjacent to SOX in column K.
- An 8-letter bingo starting with R in row 14.

(Of course there are more bingo possibilities, such as a 9-letter bingo involving TI in row 13 like RETICULAR, but in general when you're looking for bingos, you start with 7-letter words and then only move on to 8-letter, 9-letter, etc. The probability of those longer bingos drop quickly with length.)

If you play WOE, you do not change this calculus. If you play WILL, then you add two more bingo lanes in row 12 and 13.* In other words, if you're up 70 points, you should play WOE, and WILL if you're down 70. You mention leave, and NRO is better than LLRNI when you're looking for a bingo, which is another argument in favor of WILL if you're down 70.**

There're a couple more considerations. The more important one is that, right now, it's not easy to find a place to play on the board, because the board is closed. An important possible place to play is next to SOX, but it's not trivial to fit a word here because X only forms two two-letter words: XI and XU. There are 9 I's and 4 U's. Two U's and six I's have been played, and you hold an I, which means you are probably better-able to exploit this point better than your opponent. This is another argument in favor of WOE, since you preserve the I for future use.

The other consideration is turnover. If you play WILL, you see four new tiles. If you play WOE, you only see two. Seeing more tiles is good, but giving up points is not. 6 points is usually too large to lose for turnover of two extra tiles.

**tl; dr**: WOE is *probably* the better play. The exception is if you're down 70+ points and need to gamble to win.

---

*WILL takes two back hooks, WILLS and WILLY, and there are 2 S's and 1 Y still out there.

**Yet another argument in favor of WILL if you're down 70+ points is that you really want to find an S or Y, to enable a bingo, making turnover more important.